# Right bar button item action is not working on iOS11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, ios11

I have created a right action bar item button using the following code. This code is working fine below iOS 11, but not working on iOS 11.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"SAVE", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(updateButtonTapped)];
```

Comment: selector method is not being called.

Comment: Is this related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46278620/ios11-uibarbuttonitem-not-working

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same thing in Beta 6. Not a good solution but for me it works if you add it in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this out and all I was missing was a

`navigationBar.sizeToFit()`

so `navigationBar = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: navigationBar.bounds.height)` without it is useless.

It seems that even if the navigationBar looks correct on screen, its height is actually 0. I even added a UITapGestureRecognizer to the navigationBar and it was still not being called. Hope this helps! Tested on Xcode 8.3.3 and Xcode 9 GM, including on iPhone X.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to 
[UIBarButtonItem not clickable on iOS 11 beta 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854203/uibarbuttonitem-not-clickable-on-ios-11-beta-7/46899749)
which includes my solution to manually set the size of the containing UIView to non-zero.