# iOS11 UIBarButtonItem not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, ios11

I have an app that is live in the store. I am trying to get it ready for the iOS11 release but have run into an annoying problem.

None of the `UIBarButtonItem`s in the app are working properly. The leftBarButtonItems are clickable but the click area is slightly to the right of the item. The rightBarButtonItems are not working at all! I have added the items both via the storyboard and via code but none of them seem to be working. Please help!

Here's an example:-

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("Save", comment: "save button title"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(VC.rightBarButtonClicked(_:)))
```

Comment: Could you check Safe Area ? Refer - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same issue. It came down to an extension on UIButton in a file called "UIButton+MinimumTouchArea.swift" in our project which overrides UIButton.hitTest and breaks UIBarButtonItem in iOS 11. It took us a the whole day to figure out!

Comment: thank you! turns out a previous dev that overridden the hitTest area of the buttons and that was screwing it up!

Answer (score 1):

[iOS11 UIBarButtonItem action not get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45928626/ios11-uibarbuttonitem-action-not-get-called)

ran into the same, solution for me was to build with xcode 8.3 instead (devices with ios11 running the app build by 8.3 worked great)

[Use Xcode 8 with iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381860/use-xcode-8-with-ios-11) you can use this workaround to debug ios11 devices on xcode 8.3

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I am doing right now as well but there should be a way to solve this problem with Xcode9 since I made a sample app and downloaded another open source project, both of which work fine

Answer (score 0):

Yes there bug in `iOS 11` so you can use another way for it.

Use `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` like

```
 self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self as! UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
```

and implement delegate method like

```
 func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        guard gestureRecognizer == interactivePopGestureRecognizer else {
            return true // default value
        }

        // Write you code here.
    }
```